# Add page level javascript to multiple PDF's as a batch

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I want to add javascript code which will be executed on page open of a single page PDF. There will be multiple files for which this needs to be done and I was wondering if there is any way of batching this instead of manually editing each PDF.

I found sources on the web and libraries which allow you to programmatically add *document level* javascript (e.g. http://blog.rsmoorthy.net/2012/01/add-javascript-to-existing-pdf-files.html)

However I haven't been able to find anything for programmatically adding *page-open* javascript. Any pointers regarding this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an additional action dictionary to your page, from adobe spec about additional actions:

> I.2.8 Additional-actions dictionaries (see Section
>   8.5.2, “Trigger Events”) can be the value of the AA entry of a catalog, page, annotation or field dictionary.
>
> TABLE 8.45 Entries in a page object’s additional-actions dictionary
>   ...
>   **Key:** PO 
>   **Type:** dictionary 
>   **Value:** (Optional; PDF 1.5) An action to be
>   performed when the page containing the annotation is opened (for
>   example, when the user navigates to it from the next or previous page
>   or by means of a link annotation or outline item). The action is
>   executed after the O action in the page’s additional-actions
>   dictionary (see Table 8.45) and the OpenAction entry in the document
>   catalog (see Table 3.25), if such actions are present.
>   ...

You could add a Javascript action there with the code you need to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your documents are one-page ones you might try to just add an action that will be executed when document is open. This is `OpenAction` in the document catalog (@yms already mentioned it).